# How do I turn off the flash notification on login and logout?

Tags: authentication, web2py

When logging in/out using the default Auth forms, a flash notification message appears in a box,  "Logged in" and "Logged out" respectively.  How do I make it so these messages do not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user3283690 answer gave me the idea that setting the message to the empty string was all that was needed to stop the flash message from showing.  This makes sense because the following line in layout.html:

`<div class="flash">{{=response.flash or ''}}</div>`

Looking at the `Auth` class in [web2py-root-directory]/gluon/tools.py I saw there was dictionary called `default_messages` with entries for `logged_in` and `logged_out`.  So I tried setting the following in db.py:

```
auth.messages.logged_in = None
auth.messages.logged_out = None
```

And it worked

Answer (score 1):

In language folder I edited default.py from

```
'Logged in': 'Logged in',
```

to

```
'Logged in': '',
```

That removes the message. But I guess you have to do the same change for all language files you wanna use.

Comment: Thanks this does work althought I'd also like to know how to do it without editing this file if possible